# AspNetIdentity framework Code first Approach

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, code-first

I am new to Code first Approach on EF6. So please excuse

I am trying to implement AspNetIdentityframework for my local project.

I have all the tables which comes out of the box in the database.I kept as is same with the model class structure.I have no roles just 1 role.

Here is my DbContext class for this.

```
 public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public AuthDbContext()
            : base("AuthDbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<AuthDbContext>(null);
        }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(t => t.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(t => t.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasKey<string>(t => t.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(t => new { t.RoleId,t.UserId});

            modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserRole>();
            modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetRole>();
}
```

I have 2 users in the table. I am trying to find one .
I am getting error Invalid Column Name 'Discriminator'
 What is that I am doing wrong in generating the model ?
I tried lot of options I could not solve this one

Here is the sql generated for userManager.FindByName Method

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
        [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Limit1].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Limit1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
        [Limit1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
        [Limit1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
        [Limit1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
        [Limit1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
        [Limit1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
        [Limit1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
        [Limit1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
        [Limit1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
        [Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
            [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
            [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
            [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
            [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
            [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
            [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
            [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
            [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
            [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
            [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
            ''0X0X'' AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N''User'') //Error here ?????????
AND (((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName]) IS NULL) AND (UPPER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL)))
        )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'testUser'
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-beta1-140129/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs) in the sources of Asp.NET Identity 2.0, `IdentityDbContext<T>` already 
defines the `DbModelBuilder` configuration in `OnModelCreating` and the 
`DbSet<AspNetRole>`,
`DbSet<AspNetUserClaim>`,
`DbSet<AspNetUserLogin>`,
`DbSet<AspNetUser>`, so you don't have to define all those properties, nor override the `OnModelCreating`.

Your Context should look something like this:

```
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AuthDbContext() : base("AuthDbContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AuthDbContext>(null);
    }
}
```

You are defining a `DbSet<AspNetUser>` and your Context inherits from `Identity<IdentityUser>` so there are 2 `DbSets`, one where `T` is `IdentityUser` and another where `T` is `AspNetUser`. `IdentityUser` inherits from `AspNetUser`, so `EntityFramework` manages inheritance by adding a column called Discriminator.

Edit:

Here is the implementation of the class you're inheriting from.

```
/// <summary>
/// DbContext which uses a custom user entity with a string primary key
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TUser"></typeparam>
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser> 
        : IdentityDbContext<
            TUser, 
            IdentityRole, 
            string, 
            IdentityUserLogin,
            IdentityUserRole,
            IdentityUserClaim> 
        where TUser : IdentityUser 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor which uses the DefaultConnection
    /// </summary>
    public IdentityDbContext()
        : this("DefaultConnection") 
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor which takes the connection string to use
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nameOrConnectionString"></param>
    public IdentityDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString) 
    { }
}
```

As you can see, the class `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` inherits from `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>`. The latter already defines properties of type `IDbSet<TRole>` and `IDbSet<TUser>`, and already has an implementation of `OnModelCreating` that in my opinion satisfies your needs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps table names, and sets up relationships between the various user entities
/// </summary>
/// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
    }

    // Needed to ensure subclasses share the same table
    var user = modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
    user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
    user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
    user.Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired();

    // CONSIDER: u.Email is Required if set on options?

    // Look into IValidatable...

    // Try this (Configure Join table name HasMany.WithMany.Map(To match 1.0 tables)
    modelBuilder.Entity<TUserRole>()
        .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
        .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

    modelBuilder.Entity<TUserLogin>()
        .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
        .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

    modelBuilder.Entity<TUserClaim>()
        .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

    var role = modelBuilder.Entity<TRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
    role.Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired();
    role.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
}
```

If you want to use your own `AspNetRole`, `AspNetUserClaim`, and `AspNetUserLogin`, you should inherit from `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>` and pass your custom entities, or if you want to really have control of your database you should simply inherit from `DbContext` and do all the setup yourself (thing you're already doing).

I hope I was clear, if you have any doubt don't hesitate in posting a comment.

Comment: this gave me a tip. i had to make other changes as well.thanks!